# Symfony ChoiceType returning wrong values in dropdown

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

This is my code in the FormType class

```
$builder
->add ( 'projects' , ChoiceType::class , ['choices' => $this->getAllProjects ()
```

with above I am only able to get a 0-4 number in the dropdown (5 records in DB)

instead of showing these numbers I want to show available names

[image: dd]

Comment: Hi @msg, thanks for replying. I tried EntityType earlier but as I not using Doctrine orm it's giving me an error

Comment: What does the method `getAllProjects` return? It should be an associative array with keys corresponding to the labels. Maybe you just return here an array without keys?

Comment: Yes, it returns an associative array. 'name'=>'ABC'

Comment: The array returned by `getAllProjects` should be in the form `'label' => 'value'`, you seem to be returning an integer indexed array.

Answer (score 0):

```
->add('projects', ChoiceType::class, [
        'choices' => $this->getAllProjects(),
        'choice_label' => function($choice, $key, $value) {
            return $value->getName(); // you know your getter
            //return $value['name']; //if the return of the getAllProjects is an associative array
        },
])
```

The point is that, the $value inside the anonymous function is an elem from your countable (from the 'choices'):

[symfony.com/forms/types/choice.html#choice-label](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-label)